# Change error message " Something Went wrong" in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, content-search-web-part

I have used Content Search webpart on my page. If something does not load, it give message:

> Something went wrong.

I want to customize this message to show some user friendly message in SharePoint Online. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, now Microsoft owns the Server Side there is now way to hack the back-end like in the olden days

Comment: thank you for the reply Danny. Any idea if we can get hold of the event that shows this message in the content search webpart in case of error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the answer, we can change the text of error message "Something went wrong" in display template in content search web part. Edit the web part, click on settings and write your custom error message in "Alternate error message".

Comment: can u please explain in more detail how and where to change text?